# Is a double Schengen visa application necessary?

Tags: visas, schengen, applications

If I have an application pending with the German embassy, for a residence permit. Can I apply for another Schengen tourist visa (Spain), since the residence application takes a long time?

I'd like to know if I can go ahead and do a second application since the first one will take a long time and I also need the tourist visa to go to another country.

Answer (score 1):

you might be able to. I had a similar situation where my long stay visa D for Switzerland was being processed and I applied for a C Visa for tourism purposes at another embassy. I was given both and the visa officer told me the overlap in dates are fine as they are two separate visas.